# PHP Version 5.6.30 for Windows acts like Version 7.0

Tags: php, windows, version

I'm working on bringing some ten year old PHP code up to date and I wanted to work on this on my Windows PC.  This code is functioning on the server which has PHP Version 5.6.23 but on my PC with PHP Version 5.6.30 I'm getting, "Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()" for example.  If I update that to mysqli_connect the error moves to mysql_query.  Basically everything that was only supposed to be deprecated is missing as though I were using version 7.0.

I know I need to update all of this anyway but I like to start with the code working.  Can anybody me tell what could be the problem?

Comment: Your workstation's PHP install doesn't have the mysql extension loaded.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The version of PHP you are using likely does not have the "mysql" extension enabled by default.

First, look in PHP's `ext/` subdirectory and ensure that `php_mysql.dll` exists - if it does not, then you'll need to download a different package which includes it (assuming one exists).

Next, edit your `php.ini` file, find the "Dynamic Extensions" section, and ensure that the `extension=php_mysql.dll` line is not commented out. If it is already uncommented, then you may be missing other dependencies.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you so very much.